# datasheet register address is not in HEX?

Tags: i2c, datasheet, hex

I am reading the [this datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/CAP1188.pdf) for the CAP1188 touch sensor and can't figure out what these "register addresses" in the far left column mean. I am used to seeing HEX addresses in datasheets such as `0x00`, `0x72` etc., but this datasheet is adding an `h` to the end of.... I don't even know I just don't get it.

For example, I am porting [this library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CAP1188_Library/blob/master/Adafruit_CAP1188.h) which has all these addresses in HEX form, but how did they get say `0x29` from `03h`?

[image]

Comment: The 0x prefix and format originates from the C language. 0xNN is not a universal format for hex numbers, merely a commonplace one. Others exist: 6502 assembly language uses $NN, VHDL uses X"NN" or 16#NN and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those addresses are also in hex. `0x1F` means the same as `1Fh`. The `XXh` notation comes from Intel assembly syntax ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11735095/1424875))

Those addresses are used to identify a device register in the I2C transaction and are orthogonal to the address of the device on the bus. In particular, the device address is given on page 17, as a function of how a certain pin is configured:

[image]

The device address 29h corresponds with a 150k pulldown resistor on the address configuration pin. Note that this is a 7 bit address; the 8th bit is used by I2C to distinguish reads and writes.

Comment: Yep, back from the good old days. But all-alphabetic numbers like FFh looked like a label so they had to be zero-prefixed e.g. 0FFh.

Answer (score 1):

0x29 is one of the available I2C addresses, it has nothing to do with the internal register addresses.

The trailing h is just another way of designating a hex number (03h is the same as 0x03).

Comment: For reference, you'll also see h'xx (i.e., 0x29 == 29h == h'29).  There's no standard; get used to it.